# Regexp to turn <div><img ...></div> into <div><img ... /></div> in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to finish closing an image tag in the middle of some other HTML, since when I create it with JS, and then send it to myself, it isn't closed properly. I'm using Python for this.

Given this string:

```
<div><img src="/images/someImage.png" alt="Some Image"></div>
```

How can I get

```
<div><img src="/images/someImage.png" alt="Some Image" /></div>
```

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
re.sub("<img(.*)(?<!/)>", "<img\\1 />", x)
```

And with just the image, it works, but once I add the `div`'s to surround it, it puts it in the wrong spot:

```
<div><img src="http://sh.local/images/tripAlbums/2014/thumbs/Background%20Default.jpeg"></div />
```

As you'll notice, the ending DIV has what I want on the image tag.

Note that although I'm only showing one image, there may be more, so it should work with a global `re.sub`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use non greedy `.*?`

```
>>> re.sub("<img(.*?)(?<!/)>", "<img\\1 />", str)
'<div><img src="/images/someImage.png" alt="Some Image" /></div>'
```

**OR**

You can also try

```
>>> re.sub("<img([^>]*)(?<!/)>", "<img\\1 />", str)
'<div><img src="/images/someImage.png" alt="Some Image"/></div>'
```

- `[^>]*` Negated character class. matches anything other than `>` *zero or more* times

---

**Cleaner method**

A cleaner and beautifull method will be using `BeautifulSoup`

```
>>> import bs4
>>> str='<div><img src="/images/someImage.png" alt="Some Image"></div>'
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(str)
>>> soup.prettify()
u'<div>\n <img alt="Some Image" src="/images/someImage.png"/>\n</div>'
```

**Note** Regex is not a right tool for parsing html. Recomended to use html parsers like `BeautifulSoup`

Comment: @David Glad to hear it helped :)

Comment: Can you explain the second method? I've never see that. And I'll definitely check out Beautiful Soup.

Comment: @David I have added a small explanation to my answer. In short it matches other than `>` till it sees the first `>`, closing of the corresponding tag. It is always recomended to use html parsers such as beautiful soup to parse html. Regex is not the right tool for html parsing

Answer (score 1):

BeautifulSoup will do this job automatically for you.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> s = '''<div><img src="/images/someImage.png" alt="Some Image"></div>'''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
>>> soup
<html><body><div><img alt="Some Image" src="/images/someImage.png"/></div></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s='<div><img src="/images/someImage.png" alt="Some Image"></div>'
n=s.find('<img')
result=s[:n+1]
s=s[n+2:]
n=s.find('>')
result=result+s[:n]+" / "+s[n:]
print result
```

Comment: Umm, that's rather ugly considering all I needed was another `?`. Nor does it use a regex, which was the question. See the other answer for the right way to do this.